# How to showcase a web application which hasn't been published yet?

Tags: resume, linkedin, portfolio

I want to showcase a dynamic web application I created while I apply for job offers as a web developer. I used HTML5, CSS3, Javascript, Bootstrap, JQuery, Ajax, API calls, JSON, some JQUERY plugin, and Javascript library. I aim to show the technologies I know on my LinkedIn profile and resume. The web application is in progress, and I don't want to share it publicly yet, though.

I want to provide something to show both the code and some demo of the website when I apply for job offers.

For the moment I uploaded the code on GitHub as a private project; therefore I may provide a link to it; I also added some screens of the app together with a video which shows how it works.

I wonder if it's a good idea to share the code and the demo on Linkedin and on my resume before I publish it under my name? Should I prevent someone from stealing it?

Which is the better option to show my proficiency as a web developer and prevent someone from stealing my app at the same time? Another option would be purchasing a domain and a hosting service (to say "I published it first; therefore it's mine"); I may link to it on my Linkedin profile then: it's a good option?

Comment: Is there any harm to hosting it before it's finished?

Comment: Just to double-check, in which context you developed that application?

Answer (score 4):

You can write a series of blog posts on how do you write your application with the snippets of the code. In your posts you can decide how deep do you want to go into your application. For example if you do not want to give out the idea behind the application since you want to be first on the marker you still can share how did you implement some generic things. If you are just creating an application to showcase your skills you can start all the way from explaining your initial vision on the drawing board/piece of paper till the very last commit with full listings or links to the specific commits etc. In the latter case you would also be able to demonstrate how your vision evolves over the time as well as you might discover some really nit trick and it would demonstrate how you learn things and incorporate into your projects.
And you don't need something fancy for this: Github Pages would do the work fine.

Then you can include the link to the blog in your LinkedIn, CV, etc

Answer (score 0):

It depends what have you got to lose, ie why you don't want to share it before it's finished. Are you going to be making money from this app / service? If so, it would make sense to keep the code secret before launching, but you said you don't even have a domain name yet, so I'll assume that's not the case.

Then it's just a demo. So, when is your ready date? If you know the date you know what you need to do by then, and if you know *that*, you have a **Product Roadmap**.

There you go. Buy a domain name, put your demo on the `prod` branch and keep merging your features. At the same time publish the Roadmap in a well-polished, easy to reach section (maybe a GDPR-like footer?) with your Roadmap, Linkedin, Github, Twitch and Tinder. What have you got to lose?

You're making it clear that:

1. This is a demo of your abilities
2. It's work-in-progress actively worked on
3. You're serious enough about it to write a list of features you want
4. You know how to write lists of features
5. *Oh, look, a link to his Linkedin!*

You'll also want to SEO your name in there pretty hard, so every time someone looks up your name or your project, the two are gonna be next to each other.

Answer (score -4):

The fact that you used jQuery is not a good sign.

I would refrain from demoing such an app for job interview purposes.  The industry is moving away from jQuery and towards frameworks like Angular, React, and Vue.

Telling them you're using an outdated technology will only hinder your employment chances.

Comment: There are plenty of environments where `jQuery` is precisely the correct technology. There are also plenty where NO FRAMEWORK AT ALL is the correct technology.

Comment: @JulieInAustin Plain javascript or es6 is better than jQuery.  Modern javascript can do what jQuery did.  The only environment where jQuery is correct are legacy applications.

Comment: Modern javascript is great for modern browsers doing modern things. All the world isn't new, all the world doesn't have all the RAM needed to run all the things. And some browsers aren't even running on what one would think of as a "general purpose computer". Some "web clients" aren't even browsers, for that matter. One of my many mad skilz is the ability to do things the way they were done 30 and 40 years ago. jQuery mostly just plain works. There are environments where "just plain works" is highly valued.

Comment: @JulieinAustin 90% of all browsers are based off Chromium / Blink or Webkit.  Microsoft has thrown in the towel on EdgeHTML let alone IE.  You might as well advise him to use Flash and Silverlight.  I'm doing him a favor by steering him in the right direction.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that your answer seems highly subjective, it doesn't really address the OP's concern.